# ActiveRecord Query with many to many or other Params

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relationship

I got 2 Models

- Projects (with a boolean column "hidden")
- Models

the both have a many to many relationship, so i added a migration with a projects_users table and changed the models using

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
# and
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

Now i want to do the following query:

Select all Projects where hidden is false OR "current_user" (a variable) belongs to project

Project.where("hidden = ?", false)
and
current_user.projects
works. But how to combine them into one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project.joins("projects_users").where("hidden = ? OR projects_users.user_id = ?", false, current_user.id).group("projects.id")
```

Comment: it returns an error. i used `.to_sql` and it returns `SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" projects_users...` i fixed this using raw mysql `SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects", "projects_users"...` which seems working. any ideas how to fix this in the rails query?

Comment: okay so this works: `Project.joins(", \"projects_users\"").where(...` but it looks HORRIBLE and i don't think thats the way `joins` should work. thankful for a tip how to fix this

Comment: Another solution is instead of using HBTM, you can use has many :through, in which you create a model for your join table, see here : http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off . This way you can then do `Project.joins(:project_users)`

Comment: jepp, looking good. thanks. a little addition. using this "version" with symbols i needed to add `projects.hidden` to the hidden column

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a scope for both of them. Then you can test them with your rails console window

Comment: i'm not really sure what you wean. i created a scope for not_hidden. so Project.not_hidden returns all Projects that are not hidden. but what to do with the other one?